# UICollectionView not appearing in a regular UIViewController from a storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uicollectionview

So I have an application that builds the UI from a storyboard, and I have this ViewController that needs to render both a UITableView and UICollectionView within the same scene.

So I basically created a regular UIViewController that that contains both a UITableView and a UICollectionView. The views are obviously set within the storyboard. The scene ViewController then contain a both UICollectionViewController and a UITableViewController.

I went this way cause this specific collectionView is a reuse from a very similar collection view from another place in the app. It works perfectly fine there, however, here nothing happens and the view doesn't appear there on run time. The tableView works just fine, and from what I've found so should the UICollectionView, but obviously I'm missing something. Is there something extra that a regular UIViewController needs to have (a method or a property) so that it will display the UICollectionView? Obviously I'm missing something since everything I've found about this indicates that it is possible to do it this way.
Edit:
Relevant Code in viewDidLoad:

```
self.productsCollectionViewController = [[ContentPageCollectionViewController alloc] init];
self.productsCollectionViewController.collectionView = self.collectionView;
[self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
[self.productsCollectionViewController setSectionSizes:@[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:7]]];

self.filtersTableViewController = [[ProductsFilterTableViewController alloc] init];
self.filtersTableViewController.tableView = self.tableView;
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

Comment: While the app is running, can you open the UIView Hierarchy and confirm that the `UICollectionView` is actually being rendered?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html

Comment: @WilliamSmith Thank you, it's not, and I don't understand why not, I'm relatively new to Interfacebuilder and storyboards

Comment: Without seeing your interface builder first hand it will be a little harder to diagnose, but start by checking your constraints carefully to make sure the collection view layout is valid.

Comment: @WilliamSmith the constraints _should_ be fine, since I'm just fixing all the borders to the parentview border, but the left one is aligned to the right border of the tableview. So it _should_ be unambiguous. Also removing all the added constraints doesn't change anything, it's still not there with the default constraints.

Comment: @WilliamSmith To be more specific, the only thing that has been done is that the UICollectionView was dragged into the scene, constraints added to fix it's location, then an IBOutlet created within the class of the ViewController, 

Then the only thing that is done in code is that I initialize the UICollectionViewController instance and set it's collectionView to the IBOutlet, this is identical to the process of the TableView and it works fine for that I'm puzzled why this doesn't work.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the various UICollectionViewDelegate and UIColelctionViewDataSource methods and confirm they are being hit.  While you're at it, examine the collectionView object that is passed in and look at the frame to see its size.  Also, are there any warnings (constraint or otherwise) in the output window?

Comment: @WilliamSmith no warnings on the constraints, the collectionView object has the frame {{0,0}, {1024,768}}, none of the delegate methods are ever invoked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90639/discussion-between-oz0234-and-william-smith).